# Enable my Wordpress Plugin and Theme w Remote Automatic Upgrade?

Tags: wordpress

I see several plugins in my WordPress site that are enabled for "Automatic Upgrade". It allows me to simply click a button and get the latest update installed into my site. I'd like to find out more about how to integrate this automatic upgrade routine into my own plugins.

If you know of resources or a tutorial on how to do this please share it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would think WP core will take care of the file update, no? Anyway, here's one you might find useful: http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-change-plugin-table-structure-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugins need to be hosted in a wordpress.org SVN repository to obtain that functionality. For information on getting your plugin hosted see: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/